# Showing filter options on embedded map of Carto?

Tags: carto

With Cartodb, is it possible to show the filter options on the embedded map?

The explain, I have generated a visualisation and have shared, but I want people accessing the visualisation to be able to filter the results.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to do this is by using CartoDB.js, the JavaScript library to build your own application. [This lesson](http://academy.cartodb.com/courses/03-cartodbjs-ground-up/lesson-3.html) shows how to do it.

If you don't want to do JavaScript, you can create a multilayer map with each each layer being from the same original data table but with a different query applied to each. I made [this](http://cdb.io/1D7Jf5D) map, by starting with one dataset and then clicking "add layer" and selecting the same dataset again. Once there are two layers, I applied different SQL to them. For example, something like this:

1st one:

`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE var > 10`

2nd one:

`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE var <= 10`

After that, you can turn on "layer selector":

[image]

Finally, you can toggle the layers in the upper right once the layer selector is toggled on:

[image]

Comment: Hi the lesson link above is dead. Does anyone know where it lives now? This is the original link https://carto.com/academy/courses/03-cartodbjs-ground-up/lesson-3.html

Comment: It's in GitHub here: https://github.com/CartoDB/academy/blob/master/_app/_cartojs-ground-up/03-basic-interactivity.md